# VS 2019 hanging on Build / Clean

Tags: build, visual-studio-2019

I am having an issue with visual studio 2019. When I try to build a project it hangs on

Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: TheProjectNameHere, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

. It does this for builds and cleans. I found on another post that you could fix this by deleting the .vs folder and restarting visual studio, for me however I have to delete the .vs and restart my computer entirely.  The issue seems to be a bit random, sometimes it happens once a week and sometimes it happens four times in a single day but either way the problem persists until I delete my .vs folder and restart my computer. The issue happens across multiple projects some in asp.net MVC and some in Blazor WASM so I don't think the projects themselves are the issue.

I have tried opening the projects with VS2022, updating VS, repairing VS, disabling the only extension I have installed.  Does anyone have any other ideas on things I could try to attempt to fix this?

Thanks in advance